# io.on method is too big,how to use routes

Tags: node.js, socket.io

`io.on("connection")` method is too big. How can i use routes?

I use `socket.io`. I could write more `on event` in my project, such as

```
const io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('event1', res=>{/* ... */});
    socket.on('event2', res=>{/* ... */});
    socket.on('event3', res=>{/* ... */});
    socket.on('event4', res=>{/* ... */});
    //more...
});
```

I want to use like routes, create a routes folder which can save more `on event` file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, but you can for example pass the socket to a registering function. This function would attach the events to a specific socket :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
   attachEvents(socket)
});

// Or more simply :
io.on('connection', attachEvents);

class Handler { // You can put that in a separate file and import it

    constructor(){ }

    event1(data) => {
         console.log("event 1 triggered", data)
    }

    event2(data) => {
         console.log("event 2 triggered", data)
    }

    event3(data) => {
         console.log("event 3 triggered", data)
    }

    event4(data) => {
         console.log("event 4 triggered", data)
    }
}

const attachEvents = socket => {
    let events = ["event1", "event2","event3", "event4"],
        handler = new Handler()

    for(event of events) socket.on(event, handler[event]) // simpler than .on(event, data => handler[event](data) )
}
```

Comment: thank you.if i use ```socket.use(()={})``` at ```define events ...for(event of events) socket.on(event, handler[event]) ``` ,is this maybe simpler? i don't know how to use it